# Indexing subwords of an URL in Solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am tying to use solr for my poc and i am struck with the below issue and not able to figure out a solution.

Any help would be very much appreciated.!!

Below are the four cases i am trying to achieve:
URLs:
1.www.abc.com
2.www.abcdef.com
3.www.123.com/abc
4.www.123.com/abcdef

I am using standard tokenizer to index the URLs which splits words as below and index.
1.www.abc.com
2.www.abcdef.com
3.www.123.com  and abc
4.www.123.com  and abcdef

When i search for abc i would get only the 3rd URL as the search result.

But i want to get all the four URLs when i search with the keyword abc.

Kinldy suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you search with string "abc" all documents with token "abc" is retrieved as result. so abc will match only abc.

to match abcde or abcd.. etc to match using query "abc", you should index document using n-grams

Read about Edge N-grams.

Add below filter in you schema file for the field analyzer type="index" to your field typr definition.

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="20" minGramSize="2"/>
```

Example: field name="abcde"

EdgeNGramFilterFactory will generate tokens like ab,bc,cd,de,abc,bcd,cde,abcd,bcde,abcde,

Comment: Thanks for your reply vinod. i think the usage of NGram is good if we have the field name of few characters and generate tokens. But in my case field is an URL whose length can be very long and so i guess in that case it create huge number of tokens.!! what do you think..

Comment: correct, it generates more number of tokens. hence both index size and indexing time will increase. No other way using solr.